# How to construct a level in categorical variable in R depending upon another categorical variable value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two `CATEGORICAL` variables.`Jobs` and `Jobless` in a data frame. All the participants having `"0"` status in Jobless variable should be in `"0"` category in `Jobs` too. So how can i construct this `0` level in categorical variable of `Jobs` depending upon variable `Jobless`. I assume some of the `NA` in `Jobs` will be replaced by this `0` category.

```
Jobs<-c("1","2","3","4",NA)
jobless<-c("0","1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
Jobs = c("1","2","3","4",NA),
jobless = c("0","1", "1", "0", "1")
)
df
#   Jobs jobless
# 1    1       0
# 2    2       1
# 3    3       1
# 4    4       0
# 5 <NA>       1

df$new_job_category <- ifelse(df$jobless == "0", "0", df$Jobs)
df
#   Jobs jobless new_job_category
# 1    1       0                0
# 2    2       1                2
# 3    3       1                3
# 4    4       0                0
# 5 <NA>       1             <NA>
```

This also replaces `NA` by "0":

```
df$new_job_category <- ifelse(df$jobless == "0" | is.na(df$Jobs), "0", df$Jobs)
df
#   Jobs jobless new_job_category
# 1    1       0                0
# 2    2       1                2
# 3    3       1                3
# 4    4       0                0
# 5 <NA>       1                0
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I assume that if the variables are in a data frame they are of the same length, and not of different length a you showed. This simplifies things.

I will thus create a data.frame with the variable job and jobless and then require that all the occurrences of job in which jobless is zero are also zero, as you required.

```
jobdf<-data.frame(job=c("1","2",NA),jobless=c("1","0","0"),stringsAsFactors=F)
jobdf$job[jobdf$jobless=="0"]<-"0"
```

I think that better ways exist using factors, but I cannot find any right now.